# Convergence in distribution and Slutsky theorem

Tags: convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

When $\{X_1,X_2,X_3,\cdots,X_n\}$ is a random sample from the population distribution $(\mu,\sigma^2)$, according to the CLT, $\bar{X} \to \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$ in distribution sense.

Then what is the approximate distribution of $2n \bar{X} / (2n+1)$?

Does it follow the same distribution as $\bar{X}$?

Is it possible to use Slutsky theorem because $2n/(2n+1)$ approximate to 1 in probability?

Comment: You are abusing the notation. You may say that $\bar{X}$ is asymptotically distributed as $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$, but the limiting distribution should not depend on $n$. And indeed, SLLN tells that $\bar{X} \to \mu$ a.s. (and hence in probability and in distribution). If you want to invoke CLT, then you may say that $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu) \to \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ in distribution.

Comment: I know that if n goes to infinity, $\bar{X}$ alone cannot have a distribution. But the thing is, the question I'm handling now invokes me to find an asymtotic distribution of 2n *xbar / (2n+1)

Comment: Can it follow a distribution?

Comment: If we write $Y_n=\frac{2n}{2n+1}\bar{X}_n$, then $$\sqrt{n}(Y_n - \mu)=\frac{2n}{2n+1}\sqrt{n}(\bar{X} - \mu) - \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2n+1}\mu.$$ By Slutsky theorem, this converges in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. So you may say that $Y_n$ is asymptotically $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$ as well.

Comment: It is possible to say that 2n/(2n+1) converges to 1 in probability right?

Comment: Yes, of course. :)

Comment: I thought it was a kind of Irony because as n goes to infinity, the variance goes to 0, forming a deterministic distribution $\mu$

Comment: You are not wrong, since $\bar{X}$ indeed converges in distribution to the degenerate distribution concentrated at $\mu$. (This either follows from LLN or CLT.) That is why I am stubbornly looking at the normalized variables $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)$ and $\sqrt{n}(Y_n-\mu)$.